# Continue SSIS Script Task after exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I created Script Task at my SSIS package. Task contains FOR loop with some processing on each iteration. And I added try-catch around loop body to handle exceptions manually. I want loop to continue after exception on some iteration, but when exception occurs, package fails. I want it just proceed to next iteration. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you catch every exception, you should be absolutely fine. Although make sure you use

`Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;`

at the end of your code.

Have a look at this as reference:

```
    public void Main()
    {   
        try
        {
            //Your piece of code that might fail
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             //Handling the exception(s)
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```